# Adding google analytics to application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-analytics

I added this code

```
function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m
)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-123mycode-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

to application.js, below the require lines.

I'm seeing a `ga.js` in my Chrome source files, but no analytics.js.

I don't see any updates on the Google Analytics page.

I'm sure this is the right site because I'm able to edit a view and see it update.

Why would this not show? Do I have to make a separate javascript file?

Comment: It looks like you're missing an opening parenthesis in the code you pasted. Is it like that in your source? If so you have a syntax error.

Comment: You should also search your code to find out where ga.js is coming from. If you load both, you'll be reporting double traffic.

Comment: I copied it from google

Comment: @PhilipWalton where shoudl the ( go? I don't see an error in the Chrome console.

Comment: You must have mis-copied. The correct way is `(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){...`, you have `function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){...` notice how yours doesn't start with a parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the code in a separate javascript file. But should be in the html page.
You have to use a common include or template to paste the code instead of manually adding it to every page.

Comment: So application.js doesn't load it? I'll try the html

Comment: That's not quite true. You can put it in a separate file, it's just not recommended because it's slower to load that way.

Comment: Separate file sounds fine. I did just try it in an HTML file. The file loads. I'm not seeing any results yet though (separate issue I guess)

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to use separate file, in your HTML file, or whatever as long as your script's source is available when your page loaded.

Google Analytic data is not instantly appeared, it need about a day to get your data if it's your first time using it. There is a way to check if your script is on the right track or not using [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/185871?hl=en).